# http client with proxy and json credentials

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, proxy, httpclient, google-compute-engine

I would like to use google api from Go. I want the api to authenticate as service account, and communicate via a proxy.
I think the solution is to create the google api service with an google api option called *ClientOption* that uses an http client, which can have the service account key and the proxy configured. This approach is suggested [here](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-go-client/issues/434#issuecomment-563422206).
I am not sure how to do it.

Creating an option to use json credentials is simple. Following is an example of how to create a gce (google compute engine) service with json credentials -

```
import (
compute "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
"google.golang.org/api/option"
)

compute.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsJSON(saKey))
```

I've also created a ClientOption that tells the api to use a proxy

```
import (
ghttp "google.golang.org/api/transport/http"
"golang.org/x/net/http/httpproxy"
"google.golang.org/api/option"
)

func getProxyOption(...) (..) {
config := httpproxy.Config{
    HTTPSProxy: httpProxy,
    HTTPProxy: httpProxy,
    NoProxy: noProxy,
}

transport, err := ghttp.NewTransport(ctx, &http.Transport{Proxy: func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    return config.ProxyFunc()(r.URL)
}   },
)
if err != nil {
    return
}
return option.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client {
    Transport: transport,
})
}
```

Either option works individually. However, creating one that uses both doesn't seem to work.

Following is my code -

```
func GetHttpClientOption(ctx context.Context, client client.Client, httpProxySecret string, saKey []byte) (httpClientOption option.ClientOption, err error) {

if saKey != nil {
    if valid := json.Valid(saKey); !valid {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("Service account key is not a valid JSON")
    }
}

httpProxy, noProxy, err := readProxySecret(ctx, client, httpProxySecret)
config := httpproxy.Config{
    HTTPSProxy: httpProxy,
    HTTPProxy: httpProxy,
    NoProxy: noProxy,
}
httpTransportOptions := make([]option.ClientOption, 0)
if saKey != nil {
    httpTransportOptions = append(httpTransportOptions, option.WithCredentialsJSON(saKey))
}

trasport, err := ghttp.NewTransport(ctx, &http.Transport{Proxy: func(r *http.Request) (*url.URL, error) {
    return config.ProxyFunc()(r.URL)
}   },
httpTransportOptions... )
if err != nil {
    return
}
return option.WithHTTPClient(&http.Client {
    Transport: trasport,
}), nil
}

func GetComputeService(...) *compute.Service {
    compute.NewService(ctx, GetHttpClientOption(...))
}
```

The code fails with the following error:

```
googleapi: Error 401: Request had invalid authentication credentials. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.
More details:
Reason: authError, Message: Invalid Credentials
```

The proxy and the credentials options both work individually.
However I can't get both to work together.

Additional info about what I'm doing (which is probably not relevant) -

1. I am running on a kubernetes cluster (v 1.17).
2. The proxy I am using is squid.
3. I don't want to set the proxy details as environment variables. That would cause other issues.

Comment: Does your proxy forward correctly the Authorization header?

Comment: I can't see how it wouldn't. (also can be hard to check). The communication is encrypted, so i don't think the proxy can change anything there. Also, squid is set up to be completely transparent. Can't really see how I could have made a mistake there. But its my first time using squid, so maybe its possible.

Answer (score 3):

```
import (
  "context"
  "golang.org/x/oauth2"
  "google.golang.org/api/compute/v1"
  "google.golang.org/api/option"
)

ctx := context.Background()
ctx = context.WithValue(ctx, oauth2.HTTPClient, httpClient)
svc, err := compute.NewService(ctx, option.WithCredentialsJSON(saKey))
```

Comment: I already solved this question, and forgot to update a solution. It was a long time and I don't fully recall the issue. But i'll give you a thumb up for an answer that might be correct.